# Barcode Scanner with Triple Scan

Tags: barcode-scanner

I tried to search in every website but still cannot find it.
I have a machine that is mounting a product that has 3 serial that is automatic pulling the product to the other machine. Is there a barcode scanner that can scan 3 serial at the same time or sequentially scanning that 3 serial? any brand is okay but if there is honeywell that will be much appreciated and if it can be mount to the machine. thank you in advance.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "I have a machine that is mounting a product that has 3 serial that is automatic pulling the product to the other machine." Do you mean there are three barcodes on each product, and you want to scan all of them simultaneously? What kind of products are these?

Comment: @JMY1000 its a PCB board it has 3 barcodes. and yes it needed to scan simultaneously automatically.